# Is there a possibility to Checkout all git Branches of one solution at the same time?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gitlab

We have a solution with mutliple projects inside. The projects hasve 2 main branches, one for 32-Bit and one for 64-Bit.

Is there a possibility to checkout all git branches at the same time when one of the projects changes branch?

e.g. if project 1 changes to the 64bit branch all other do that aswell to make sure all changes are compiled with the right projects.

I tried bash and powershell scripts with git hooks but it wont work.

We are using Visual Studio 2015 atm (yes its old) but we are planning to switch to 2019 or 2022. So if there is a solution in a newer Visual Studio Version it would be ok, too.

Comment: _"The projects hasve 2 main branches, one for 32-Bit and one for 64-Bit."_ - is that 2 _GIT_-Branches -- one for each 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Yes thats 2 Git Branches.

Comment: But in the same repository, aren't they? So when you go to your working tree and check out 32-Branch, then _everything_ should already be on that branch. To be sure, I'd do a clean/rebuild then but I don't see how that would be a problem?

Comment: Possibly https://gitbutler.com/ ?

Comment: Does each project have it's own repository, or submodule? (So if 10 projects then you have 10 repositories, with 2 branches each for 20 total branches ?)

Comment: Yes. It is one Solution with 6 Projects. Each of these 6 projects has its own repository and two Branches.If I switch one of them or everyone should switch to the according branch.